# Windows 10/11 AHCI Broken After Intel RST

Tags: intel-rst

I have a bizarre situation. I bought an ASUS Maximus XII Hero and installed Windows on it with the hardware controller set to AHCI in the BIOS; it worked.

I then installed the Intel RST driver in Windows. It asked me if I wanted to optimise the system by turning on Intel RST. I accepted.

The system reboots and is now in Intel RST mode (BIOS setting). I realised I can’t dual boot with certain BSD OS with this configuration so I wiped windows and switched back to AHCI.

I try to install Windows again and this time it says Windows can’t find the driver for this configuration. I tried again with Windows 11 and the same thing happened.

The only way I can install Windows is with Intel RST Premium. It will not work on AHCI despite this being perfectly fine the first time.

What did Intel RST do to this system?

## EDIT

This system, out of the box, was set with “Optimised Defaults” and AHCI. Windows installed without issue. From this point forward, assume that all troubleshooting I have tried is a fresh install from an “Optimised Defaults” configuration with CSM on/off and AHCI/IRST.

I wiped the drive. It is a Windows only boot drive and I completely wiped it. This means all partitions including the GPT label. I had suspicions that Windows was unable to create a GPT label (despite never having experienced this issue before) and so I tried again with a GPT label and this still failed with the same driver error. Assume from this point forward that every troubleshooting step is from a clean drive with nothing else on it as if I bought a brand new SSD and plugged it in right out of the box. For even further clarification, I have clean installed Windows 10 (at work) on hundreds of different PCs in this exact same way and never once has something like a GPT or DOS label on the disk prevented an install of Windows using AHCI, with or without legacy boot or CSM disabled/enabled—literally hundreds of different PCs with different configurations. The only time I have ever experienced this, is after the software IRST driver changed my **UEFI** setting.

## Edit

“Have you tried to reset the default UEFI configuration?”

What does this mean? It’s vague. Do you mean loading the defaults or is this a different process altogether? For further information, this issue persists after BIOS updates, which resets user changes

As far as taking pictures of my BIOS settings, I already have a full install on IRST and will not be reinstalling to test something unless it is compelling.

I have tried these suggestions (GPT/dos label, csm). I’m not sure why you don’t believe this.

Secure Boot is set to allow other OS (Otherwise I can’t install Linux). This same setting is set the same way on my Maximus VIII Hero build, and AHCI works fine

CSM is guaranteed disabled because I use GPU re-bar support which forces CSM to be disabled

## In Response to the Last Comment

I have stated clearly in the last round of updates that I have loaded the defaults of the UEFI. This is the only stack where I have experienced this phenomena where people aggressively ignore someone's troubleshooting steps. This is also the only stack where I have experienced users aggressively insisting that their incorrect diagnosis must be the culprit (DOS/GPT labels on a clean disk).

Comment: Change the UEFI settings back to AHCI *before* booting the installer.

Comment: UEFI replaced BIOS more than a decade ago. What you call BIOS - wrongly - is UEFI. Please re-check as you may think you did but didn't or you may think you saved but didn't.

Comment: @brokaryote - You should [edit] your question to include all the vital information in your temporary commentary.  When you reinstalled Windows, you deleted all partitions on the disk, before reinstalled Windows? Have you tried to restore the default UEFI  configuration? I cannot reinforced this enough, CSM should remain disabled, if you are uninstalling Windows in UEFI mode.  **Please do not reply to this comment with another comment.**

Comment: The number one reason, Windows installation environment is unable to find the drivers for a device, is because the installation environment is in LEGACY/UEFI mode, while the disk is in an incompatible partition schema (GPT/MBR). If you are installing Windows, while in UEFI mode (which is the default on modern systems), then you must install to a GPT partition. *It's unlikely I will read any responses to this statement if you submit a comment directed towards me.* You should [edit] your question to provide the necessary clarification so the question can be answered.

Comment: “What does this mean?” - There is an option to restore the default configuration which set the SATA mode to something other than Intel RST. “I already have a full install on IRST and will not be reinstalling to test something unless it is compelling.” - Who said anything about reinstalling anything? However, without a willing individual to troubleshoot the problem, I cannot justify any further attempts to diagnose the problem. Especially, given the non-subtle response you have had so far